# sqlalchemy: subqueryload with filter on the subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

In sqlalchemy, is it possible to filter the result in the returned by subqueryloading of a relationship? Consider the following (please ignore any syntax/api errors)

Relationship:

```
User.address = relationship(Address,
                            secondary = UserAddress,
                            primaryjoin = (User.userid == UserAddress.userid),
                            secondaryjoin = (UserAddress.addressid == Address.addressid))
```

Query:

```
session.query(User).options(subqueryload(User.addresses))
```

This will give me all addresses matching the join condition. However, what if I want to further filtering on the addresses. For example, if the user is logged in as a guest, he/she should only see another user's company address, but not his/her home address. So something like (hypothetically):

```
if user_group == 'guest':
    option = subqueryload(User.addresses).filter(Address.type != 'home')
else:
    option = subqueryload(User.addresses)
q = session.query(User).options(options)
```

This cannot be expressed as a condition in the primaryjoin or secondaryjoin. What should I do in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You want addresses, right? Just do a simple query from the other side (`user_id` is a parameter):

```
qry = session.query(Address).join(User).filter(User.id == user_id)
if user_group == 'guest':
    qry = qry.filter(Address.type != 'home')
addresses = qry.all()
```

Comment: My example is a simplified version of a bigger problem. Your solution works in that case, but I'm looking for a general solution that enables me to add additional criteria to the join condition. I'll put another problem below:

Comment: suppose I have a muti-tenant system, where tenants share the same table and are distinguished by an extra key 'systemid'. The join condition in the relationship will have Address.systemid==User.systemid, however, while querying users with addresses for a given system, if we load the relationship in a subquery, we need to add systemid=$current_systemid to the join condition or we end up with a  subquery that does a full table scan. So ``subquery.filter(Address.systemid==current_systemid)`` is needed. This is just one of the example why filtering on subquery is necessary.